# Playing sound on server using php

Tags: linux, permissions, php, arch-linux, sudo

I want to play a sound file on my server using PHP. The PHP script is called by Apache and runs under the user 'nobody', which has by default no access to the speakers. So I created a new user `soundoutput` which is allowed do play sound and has read permissions for the sound files he should play.

If I'm logged in as root, I can play a sound file using `echo password | sudo -Su soundoutput mpg321 '/path/to/sound.mp3'`. The problem is, that it doesn't work when I'm executing this command using PHP's `system_exec`. I guess that user nobody isn't allowed to run sudo, but what can I do that he is allowed to do that?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Instead of putting _nobody_ in the sudoers file (`/etc/sudoers`), which I consider a security risk, maybe you should make the script run as the _soundoutput_ user.

Comment: But how can I run this script as soundoutput? As far as I know, a PHP script is executed as the user who calls it. And for my apache server running as nobody, the script will also run as nobody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Apache as httpd instead of nobody, then run:

```
# gpasswd -a httpd audio
```

That should grant the httpd user audio privileges.

Also, what is the goal?  Have you thought of MPD?  There are countless web clients you can use if you're just trying to play music.